# Run script on multiple files sequentially?

Tags: python

I have this code which along with the rest of it runs on a single file in a folder.

I want to try and run this code on 11 files in the folder. I have to pass parameters to the whole script via an .sh script which I've written.

I've searched on here and found various solutions which have not worked.

```
def get_m3u_name():
  m3u_name = ""
  dirs = os.listdir("/tmp/")
  for m3u_file in dirs:
    if m3u_file.endswith(".m3u") or m3u_file.endswith(".xml"):
         m3u_name = m3u_file
  return m3u_name

def remove_line(filename, what):
  if os.path.isfile(filename):
    file_read = open(filename).readlines()
    file_write = open(filename, 'w')
    for line in file_read:
      if what not in line:
        file_write.write(line)
    file_write.close()

m3ufile = get_m3u_name()
```

I have tried a different method of deleting the file just processed then looping the script to run again on the next file as I can do this manually but when I use

```
os.remove(m3ufile)
```

I get file not found either method of improving my code would be of great help to me. I'm just a newbie at this but pointing me in the right direction would be of great help.

Comment: After you read all the lines of the file with `readlines()`, `close()` it before overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks, something so simple that I totally overlooked it. Added the close and then can delete the file after for cleanup and to loop to the next file.

Comment: Badge: That's good to hear. I suggest in the future—whenever possible— that you use Python's [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to ensure your files are closed automatically.